# Read the Data from FTDI through Serial Port

Tags: visual-studio, ftdi

I am trying to read real time sensor data from FTDI to C# through serial port. I have executed this code but i am not getting any data. I had already set the parameters for serial port:

- baudrate: 115200
- DataBits: 8
- StopBits: 1
- RtsEnable: True
- DtrEnable: True

Is it necessary to add FTDI library to read data?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;
using System.Timers;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        double[] a = new double[30];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            serialPort1.PortName = "COM5";
            serialPort1.DataReceived += serialPort1_DataReceived;
        }

        public void configrations()
        {
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }      

        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                int dataLength = serialPort1.BytesToRead;
                byte[] dataRecevied = new byte[dataLength];
                int nbytes = serialPort1.Read(dataRecevied, 0, dataLength);
                string line1 = Convert.ToString(nbytes * 10000);

                this.BeginInvoke(new LineReceivedEvent(LineReceived), line1);

            }
            catch { }
        }

        private delegate void LineReceivedEvent(string line1);

        private void LineReceived(string line1)
        {
            label1.Text = line1;
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            serialPort1.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need a library (if you don't have it yet). See [FTDI C# examples](https://www.ftdichip.com/Support/SoftwareExamples/CodeExamples/CSharp.htm) for more help